# How to close a fragment on clicking floating action button

Tags: android, android-fragments, floating-action-button

I am trying to implement a fab action which when once clicked starts a fragment and on touching again closes the fragment. How can I do this.

This is my code:

```
final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            /*Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();*/

            NewOrdersFragment newOrdersFragment = new NewOrdersFragment();

            if(isOpen){
                fab.startAnimation(FabRanticlockwise);
                FragmentManager orderManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                orderManager.beginTransaction().remove(newOrdersFragment);
                isOpen = false;
            }

            else{
                fab.startAnimation(FabRClockwise);
                FragmentManager orderManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                orderManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_buyer_main_area, newOrdersFragment).commit();
                isOpen = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: what do you mean by closing a [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)?

Answer (score 0):

```
beginTransaction().remove(yourFragment)
```

or

```
beginTransaction().detatch(yourFragment)
```

are handy for your case.

Comment: I tried both but it didn't work the fragment stayed as it is

Comment: the problem is that you pass a new instance of the fragment every time. try initiating the fragment once, and use that in fragmentTransaction.

Comment: I tried it this way too it didn't work. Could you please tell me how to do it.

Comment: I just saw your edited code. put  "" NewOrdersFragment newOrdersFragment = new NewOrdersFragment(); "" somewhere before the onClick method. right after instantiating your floating action button could be fine.